# Probation period passed but no formal confirmation

Tags: probation

My probation is 6 months, during this time I can leave during 2 weeks. I have been at the company for 10 months and nothing has been said about this. I have not been told I have passed probation.

After probation i need to give 2 months notice if I leave.

If I stay quiet can I leave when I want after 2 weeks as I have no had any confirmation of passing or is it an automatic approval after the stated period.

Thanks.

Comment: If your probation period is a fixed 6 months, what makes you think there'd need to be any sort of acknowledgement of it passing for it to pass?

Comment: @Dukeling because if I failed they would tell me. So surely they will let me know if I pass. The company's HR guide says they will provide written confirmation.

Comment: @AnotherUser it doesn't work like that if custom and practice is that if you pass 6 moths and don't get a negative response you have passed probation.

Comment: Legally you might be in the right, if company rules are explicit about a written notice of confirmation. But consider the after effects of leaving them with bitter feelings; if they delay your relieving letter, would it affect you now or later (some companies do ask for such letters). Also, later you may face a perception that you didn't clear probation in that stint and hence doubts on your competence. I'd say put in your resignation and say that you'd want to be relieved by date x. Ask for guidance on procedures. If they're adamant about 2 months notice, consider buying it up.

Answer (score 2):

You've passed your 6-months probation period. Had you failed, you wouldn't have been around for the past 4 months. You stayed, so it was implicit you succeeded - no explicit notice necessary.

With respect to notice periods, there's what's on paper - that is, 2 months in your case - and there's what happens in practice. I've only ever run into one company that required its employees to stay around for the entire notice period. Most will happily let you go earlier unless a) they haven't been monitoring their [bus factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_factor) and b) you've critically under-documented what you've worked on.

If you've been proactively addressing b) during your stay, the only sensible reason to keep you around would be to brief and train whoever replaces you.

Comment: It is very different outside the US... I suspect thisis india and yes they enforce notice periods