# When and how do you bring up extension when trial period is ending?

Tags: internship, contract-extension

My trial period in a company is ending in two days. Does that mean they're not going to extend my internship if I haven't heard anything from them?

Should I bring this up myself? I only have 2 days, left so should I just wait until the last day?

Comment: Pays to be proactive, no harm in bringing it up.

Comment: If your internship is, say, 6 month with a 2 week trial period, I've never heard of an explicit notification to "extend the trial period"; unless you hear from them, the regular contract still holds. Or did you sign up for a trial period without any longer term prospect in the contract?

Comment: We need to know, is this trial period the end of your internship or just the end of your probation period? Both have two very different connotations

Comment: They should have informed you either way.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is it appropriate to ask for a fulltime offer after the end of my internship?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/11978) if the trial period you're talking about is the end of your internship, not the end of your probation period.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [Probation period passed but no formal confirmation](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/98641) if we're talking about probation periods.

Answer (score 2):

> does that mean they're not going to extend my internship if I haven't heard anything from them? I only have 2 days, left so should I just wait until the last day?

The only way to know for sure, besides waiting for the outcome, is asking. Waiting until last day may not be so recommended (I would have asked aprox. a week before at least).

I suggest that you **bring it up** ASAP, and that you also start **looking for other jobs** just in case. As always, try to do it in a polite and professional way.

As mentioned before, for future reference you may do better in addressing this problem earlier.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, there isn't usually a notification for an extension of your trial period. As pmf said in the comments, your regular contract should hold, however this may depend on your contract.

The important thing is that if this troubles you, you should go talk to your manager as soon as possible to get any doubts cleared up.